# source of blank page between sections in word when printing

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word file with 2 sections. both of them have one page only. but at print time word makes a blank page between these two sections. Note that none of these sections' start are`"New Page"` and no Even Page nor Odd Page...

Also note that if the first section has 2 pages this blank page is disappeared...I don't know how we can make this behavior without even/odd section breaks?!

You can get file here to examine: [4shared](http://www.4shared.com/file/0piSi5goce/blob.html) or from [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/urrty47j75rjoyl/blob.docx)

Comment: Could you please share that document in Dropbox or other program where the downloader doesn't need to give out their Facebook or other info?

Comment: I did it karen..

Answer (score 2):

It is becuase of `"Mirror Margin"` which is set for `Multiple Pages` of section. Mirror Margin makes your document like a book. so each left page should have a right page with mirrored margin too. So if you have only one page in your section, the word created a second page for it to be able to manage mirrored margins

**P.S - Important:**

It is also completely related to at which number the section is started with. if all the sections use `"Continue from previous section"` there would be no any blank pages but if one of the sections **is defined** to start with an **odd** page number and previous section finished with an **even** page number, MS Word will produce a blank page between these two ssections.